# InvokeMember vs normal method call

Tags: c#

I am doing maintenance on a legacy system and found the following implementation in a .Net class (`GetMethod` is just an hard coded example. This comes from a config xml file). I've changed it to normal method call to make to see if it will work and did:

```
GetMethod = "ListChanges";

DataSet dsData = null;
Type currType = GetType();
dsData = currType.InvokeMember(GetMethod, 
         BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, 
                 null, 
                 this, 
                 new object[] {oWS}) as DataSet;
```

VS

```
DataSet dData = ListChanges(<Some class> var); //ListChanges defined in the class!!
```

I've read that `InvokeMember` provides certain binding contraints, however looking at this what am I failing to understand why this would improve the code instead of a normal method call?

Comment: I strongly suspect that it was trying to invoke a member that it wouldn't normally have access to, e.g. a private one. Maybe that member was later made public.

Comment: The only scenario I can imagine where this makes any kind of sense (as in, not just the same thing as calling the method directly) is when the class is part of a type hierarchy that uses inheritance, `ListChanges` isn't a virtual method, but it's still present in derived classes (using `new` to shadow the base). In that case, the `GetType().InvokeMember()` dance is a (terrible) way of invoking the derived method. Other than that, there's no sense in it. Maybe `ListChanges` was a private or protected member of the base class once, or maybe the developer just wanted to use it "because".

Comment: Thank you both OP. Both make sense. Unfortunately I cannot confirm both. To me it look unnecessarily complicated. Wouldn't `InvokeMember` add overhead because of reflection instead of a normal function call?

Comment: It does add overhead, which is why you only use reflection when you need to. On re-reading the question, though, since you say `GetMethod` is "just a hard-coded example": if you don't know the name of the method to call until runtime, because it comes from a configuration file, then reflection is your only option -- either that or a big `switch` with all the methods you allow, but that's harder to maintain. (Safer, though.)

Comment: You say "GetMethod is just an hard coded example. This comes from a config xml file". Do you mean that the value for GetMethod comes from a config file? If so then there is an obvious way in which they differ - by the second method you cannot change the method called without recompiling. Why this would be done I couldn't say...

Answer (score 0):

This is case of same method name pattern without interface. You have multiple compiler generated classes (from Typed DataSets etc),

```
class A {
    public Changes ListChanges(Object a){
      ...
    }
}

class B {
    public Changes ListChanges(Object a){
      ...
    }
}
```

Both class A and B have same method signature with method name "ListChanges" but both do not implement interface.

Developer may have done this to efficiently call method by using reflection assuming you could easily use this method for without worrying about types.

Normally we would define `partial` classes and add interface to generated classes, but may be this code is very old (Typed datasets are very old), `partial` did not exist at time of development and writing custom code generator would be way too much to code for simply calling single method.